# Android - Listview with viewholder changing background of selected row on press

Tags: android, android-listview, row, android-viewholder

I've been looking up posts all over this site and others, but ave not found working code for what I need. I currently have a listview with custom rows, and I have them alternate by color (grey and transparent). I am trying to get the selected row to become blue (and to go back to original color when another row is pressed), and stay selected even when I scroll away from it.

EDIT: here is the complete list adapter, minus how a few icons are populated:

```
public class MultiActivateAdapter  extends ArrayAdapter<Model> {

private final List<Model> list;
private final List<Model> listInfo;
private final List<Model> listAlert;
private final List<Model> listSecondAlert;

private int _index = -1;

ArrayList<String> selectedStrings = new ArrayList<String>();

private final Activity context;
boolean checkAll_flag = false;
boolean checkItem_flag = false;

public MultiRenewAdapter2(Activity context, List<Model> list, List<Model> listInfo, List<Model> listAlert, List<Model> listSecondAlert) {
    super(context, R.layout.multirenewrow2, list);
    this.context = context;
    this.list = list;
    this.listInfo = listInfo;
    this.listAlert = listAlert;
    this.listSecondAlert = listSecondAlert;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    protected TextView text;
    protected ImageView alert;
    protected CheckBox checkbox;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();

    ViewHolder viewHolder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.multiactivaterow, null);

        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.alert = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.alert);
        viewHolder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.label);
        viewHolder.checkbox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.check);

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        convertView.setTag(R.id.label, viewHolder.text);
        convertView.setTag(R.id.check, viewHolder.checkbox);

    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
        viewHolder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                int getPosition = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();  // Here we get the position that we have set for the checkbox using setTag.
                list.get(getPosition).setSelected(buttonView.isChecked()); // Set the value of checkbox to maintain its state.

            }
        });


    if (position == _index)
    {
        convertView.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.DeepSkyBlue));
    }
    else
    {
        convertView.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.transparent));
        if (position % 2 == 0)
        {
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        }
        else
        {
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
        }
    }


        viewHolder.checkbox.setTag(position); // This line is important.

    //some code removed to show icon population

    viewHolder.text.setText(list.get(position).getName());
    viewHolder.checkbox.setChecked(list.get(position).isSelected());

    return convertView;
}

public void setClicked(int index)
{
    _index = index;
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
}
```

And the code from the older activity to which the adapter used to belong:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, int position, long id) {

                try {
                    adapt.setClicked(position);

                } catch (Exception e)  {
                    System.out.println(e);
                }
                adapt.notifyDataSetChanged();
....
```

This code used to work for all of my other listViews, but I had to change things up due to it using/relying on different arrays and other things, that allowed me to save the selected checkboxes that are displayed.

Comment: Pls post more code for us to help you. Anyway I posted 2 answers to get you started.

Comment: I posted a bit more, but let me know if you need anything else. All of this code is from the adapter.

Comment: In getView(), there are 2 lines of code that does not make sense.
View vi = convertView;
vi = inflator.inflate(R.layout.row_history, null);
Perhaps remove vi = convertView code.

Comment: The code block of "if (convertView == null)", where is it located? Normally it is at getView but it does not say. If so, please post it with getView().

Comment: Post your R.layout.row_history xml too. Is vi object supposed to be the ListView UI?

Comment: I had that commented out already but double checked for any other instance. And convertView() == null is located in the getView() method.

Comment: And the row_history was copied over from another listView. The code I have works there, but because this page uses viewHolders due to checkboxes, the same code did not work.

Comment: I posted another answer related to a previous answer due to your latest posted code. This time I can see code issues. However I think you should post multiselectrow layout in case that may be relevant, and it may.

Answer (score 1):

Now your code is starting to look clearer, even though it can use a cleanup job by removing the old or partial/duplicated code. My code suggestion is below. Basically you should set the Checkbox listener outside the if/else block of convertView == null. Both conditions need the Checkbox event.

```
if (convertView == null) {
    convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.multiselectrow, null);

    viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
    viewHolder.alert = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.alert);
    viewHolder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.label);
    viewHolder.checkbox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.check);
    convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    convertView.setTag(R.id.label, viewHolder.text);
    convertView.setTag(R.id.check, viewHolder.checkbox);

} else {
    viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
}
viewHolder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    int getPosition = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();  // Here we get the position that we have set for the checkbox using setTag.
    list.get(getPosition).setSelected(buttonView.isChecked()); // Set the value of checkbox to maintain its state.

    setClicked(getPosition);     // NEW
    }
});
if (position == _index) {
...
```

A major issue is I don't see clearly where you're setting _index. I noticed it is in setClicked event from your notes, but where is that relative to your other code? Clarity could be better.

Anyway, the design of using the event listener to set the _index and checking for the variable in getView presents a problem in **synchronization**. An event or button may be clicked but that does not necessarily trigger the getView method for refresh. Do try it out first for your education and see if your design can work but sorry I have doubts.

Comment: Try my answer for good learning. Don't get too discouraged. If the design does not work, actually a better solution, I think, is using the idea of custom List Selector, made for ListView UI.

Comment: Thank you and I have tried your answer but it did not work, but the code does look a bit more understandable. And I added some code/explanations of what you asked, hope that could help. I really appreciate all of the time and effort you are putting in to help me!

Comment: Still not clear, sorry. Where is setClicked() called? Did I misunderstood about "viewHolder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener"? I thought it is in getView(). Is it not? It seems you're contradicting me, so again there is a misunderstanding. How about just post your full Adapter code to save time?  More or less, I know your Adapter code well so I don't need the explanations. However your original posts now have few inconsistencies (especially on code) to mislead readers.

Comment: Whatever your changes are by now, just post it. So that I don't misunderstand your attempts.

Comment: I have just posted the adapter and removed the other code to avoid confusion.

Comment: Thanks for your new post. I think that might attract more readers due to better clarity. Anyway, I think we're getting somewhere though I still have doubts about the design. I have added code to call setClicked() with comments of "NEW". Your current code does not call that method at all. From now on, I'll add "NEW" comments if it different than your current code (I hope they are current).

Comment: setClicked method is public. Why is that? Is your MultiActivateAdapter   object call setClicked? If so, then I do not see that part of code. Otherwise change it to private type, so that will NOT be misleading. The other code in your Adapter looks fine.

Comment: It was public before due to older code which called it with the position. But to get this current listview to work while saving checkboxes as well, I had to use completely different code, so it is no longer used. I have changed it to private. Do you think I should still call it from the activity in the on click listener of the listview, or inside the adapter? I will also include the code from the older activity which called it, but no longer works with the new code. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe setClicked() should be called from the Activity on a click listener. I did suggest to call that method inside your getView() in onCheckedChanged. Did it work, at least somewhat? Did a row turned blue when the row is selected, like you expected?

Comment: After your code updates, pls post them, especially if related to the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I normally set attributes on a certain UI element like TextView, instead of convertView. Try this in your layout:

```
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

This could highlight on the view once it is selected. I normally set them to **false** since I don't need to highlight a row item.

Comment: This did not work. My rows have CheckBoxes in them and I had to set both values to false for it, just so the row/textView itself is selectable. I tried in addition to the false, to set true to either the entire row or just the textView, but both made the checkbox steal the focus, despite still being set to false.

Answer (score 0):

I think your approach is not exactly correct, most of your code should NOT be inside the block `if(convertView == null)`. Because if convertView is NOT null, you still have to set the attributes like `setBackgroundResource`, make sense?

And I don't see any code reference to ListView like you said. Here's a good and best tutorial to give you a good start since you have much to work on.
Link @ [Android ListView Checkbox Example](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-checkbox-example.html). Keep us posted...Tommy Kwee